# How to get all properties of all users in SharePoint 2013 Rest API?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, user-profile

I am using this code to get all properties for just myself (current user). But how can I change this so that I can get the same data but for all the users in SharePoint?

```
var oldurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties";


jQuery.ajax({
    url : oldurl,
    type : "GET",
    //data: JSON.stringify(theData),
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success:function(data){
        var f = JSON.stringify(data);
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error:function(jqxr,errorCode,errorThrown){
        alert(jqxr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: were you able to figure this out? when you get siteusers you get a lot of old users that were removed from the directory and presumably don't have access anymore too.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get all users of site then

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/SiteUsers"
```

If You want to display information of User in site then

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList"
```

Display particular user information then

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetUserById("+UserID+")"
```

But in your case if you want to get all user's properties then you need to loop through and get user profile. You can also use CSOM by which you can get all user and Groups.

You can use this method to retrieve particular property of user ([Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj667887.aspx))

```
SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName, propertyName)
```

You can get the idea from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548279/how-to-get-with-sharepoint-client-apis-all-user-profiles) how to retrieve all user properties.

I got the reference from this [Article](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/53/)

Comment: This may also help you
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/22/get-all-users-and-groups-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 5):

That can be specified by the URL that you use:

1. Get all properties of current user:

   ```
   http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
   ```
2. Get all properties of Specific User:

   For Office 365/SharePoint Online:

   ```
   http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|user@domain.com'
   ```

   For SharePoint 2013 On-Premise:

   ```
   http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\username'
   ```

Comment: I knew this but is there one for like getPropertiesForAllUsers? Like how can I get this without making a ton of requests?

Comment: Robert, as per the msdn documentation there should be no, accountName= parameter in the GetPropertiesFor method call.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx#bk_PeopleManagerGetPropertiesFor

But when I try calling the endpoint without one I get an error. Your way it works. Where did you learn you need to add the accountName=@v parameter? It's a little dicomforting if the official documentation is wrong.