# The query string "accountName" is missing or invalid

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to call the `getpropertiesfor?  SharePoint Online's REST endpoint.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx#bk_PeopleManagerGetPropertiesFor

I'm logged in and am just pasting the url into the browser. I am web encoding the string parameter `@v`. So my complete URL looks like this.

`https://domain.sharepoint.com/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getpropertiesfor(@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cuser.name%40domain.com'`

Still I only get the error message.

**The query string "accountName" is missing or invalid.**

Any pointers on what's wrong? If I call an endpoint without parameters, like the `/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager.gettrendingtags` endpoint it works and I get a correct response.

Comment: The call should look like this: 
`http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|user@domain.com'`
Reference: 
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/148320/10271

Comment: Thanks, so weird, I can swear I've tried all permutations of everything, from start to end, twice. Nothing worked. Now all of the sudden it works. :) Well, I must have made an error somewhere. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I am getting the same error. my user name is **eaonn.o'roure@domain.com** what should I do to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 8):

I also had the same issue but resolved it finally;

**Resolution**:
all the characters should be encoded after **@v=** (as below)

@v=%27i%3A0%23.f%7Cmemb‌​ership|user@domain.c‌​om%27

Full URL will be:
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropert‌​iesFor(accountName=@‌​v)?@v=%27i%3A0%23.f%7Cmemb‌​ership|user@domain.c‌​om%27

Answer (score 0):

As Mx writes in the comment the url formatted as shown here works.

http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropert‌​iesFor(accountName=@‌​v)?@v='i:0%23.f|memb‌​ership|user@domain.c‌​om'

Still not sure where the "accountName=@v" addition comes from though. In the documentation (see link in first post) there's no mentioning you have to specify "accountName=", just that you have to supply your account name as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that worked for me. After you encode the account name, you still need to replace ':' and '#'.

```
var encodeAccountName = encodeURI(accountName);
encodeAccountName = encodeAccountName.replace(':', '%3A');
encodeAccountName = encodeAccountName.replace('#', '%23');
```

In the url you also need to replace '@' in the ?@v= to ?%40v=

```
'/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountname=@v, propertyname=\'Department\')?%40v=\'' + encodeAccountName + '\''
```

This is working as this time of writing.