# How to get delve url of SharePoint Online user using JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, delve

I am having user id of SharePoint Online user. Now I need to fetch the Delve profile url for this user.

How can I fetch the Delve URL of user by User ID?

I have gone through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/query-Office-graph-using-gql-with-search-rest-api). This does not provided delve URL when I tried.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using following url:

```
SiteUrl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|user@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'
```

Using this URL in REST API will give you all properties.

Found reference [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/148320/30145)

Answer (score 3):

To get the delve url of current user, you can hit below url:

```
https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx?v=profile
```

If you want the delve url of another user, you can hit below url:

```
https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx/?p=user.name%40tenantname.com&v=work
```

So, if a user's name is say, Gautam Sheth and he has valid email address like

`gautam.sheth@abc.com` or `gautam.sheth@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com`, then url be like:

`https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx/?p=gautam.sheth%40abc.com&v=work`

or

`https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx/?p=gautam.sheth%40tenantname.onmicrosoft.com&v=work`

Comment: I agree... Thanks for the answer. What I am having is userid and if I want to fetch the delve url using REST API, then in that case is it possible to get the delve url using rest api?

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. Assuming that you are using `_spPageContextInfo.userId`, the value would be different in different site collections. However, you can use `_spPageContextInfo.userEmail` to get the email address.

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2021, I had success with the method described in this excellent article: https://tahoeninjas.blog/2019/08/19/create-a-link-to-a-delve-profile/

He even has a little fill-in form generator for the URL!

For posterity, though:

> To create a link to someone’s Delve profile:
>
> Take your tenant name, and add:
> -my.sharepoint.com/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23%2Ef%7Cmembership%7C
> to the end of it.
>
> Append the person’s email address at the end of what you got in step
> 1.

(credit to Hergo Bernier, the Tahoe Ninja).